# Azure Storage File share dll causing runtime.compiler.unsafe error at runtime when working with Azure Function V1

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, .net-4.7.2

Azure.Storage.Files.Shares v12.0.0 - 12.5.0 is giving runtime error

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Function2 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,

When we include this via Nuget in Azure Function V1.

Any workaround to use this?

I am using

```
 ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(filename);
 ShareFileDownloadInfo download = file.Download();
```

On Download() it gives this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure function v1 seems to conflict with the latest version of the package, please use `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File`.

You can refer to this code to download your file:

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(<storage-connect-string>);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(<share-name>);
            if (share.Exists())
            {
                // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
                CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(<directory-name>);

                // Ensure that the directory exists.
                if (sampleDir.Exists())
                {
                    // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                    CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("test.txt");

                    // Ensure that the file exists.
                    if (file.Exists())
                    {
                        log.Info(file.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes... thanks I had already used that, +1 for right answer